# How can I add a page from the Views module to a taxonomy menu?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

How can I add a page from the Views module to a taxonomy menu? I have a taxonomy menu like the following.

- A

  - A1
  - A2
- B

  - B1
  - B2
- C

In C, I want to display my view page output. How can I do it?

I am using drupal 6.

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 6, there's the [Taxonomy Views Integrator](http://drupal.org/project/tvi) module.

> The TVI (Taxonomy Views Integrator) module allows selective overriding of taxonomy terms and/or vocabulary with the view of your choice.